# A lookup table in netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo

I have the following list:

```
set mylist [[1 100] [3 300]]
```

and I'm uing the following to return 100 or 300 whenever my input is 1 or 3:

```
to-report itemz [a]

report item 1 (item 0 filter [(item 0 ?) = a] mylist)  

end
```

and it all works fine:

```
itemz 1
```

returns 100.

I'd like to rewrite the list so that instead of 100 it returns the value of a slider. I think I need to use the list primitive to re-create my list but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: It's a little more readable as `report last (first filter [first ? = a] mylist)`, I think.

Answer (score 3):

That's what tables are for:

```
extensions [table]
globals [mytable]

to setup
  let mylist [[1 "s1"] [3 "s2"]]
  set mytable table:from-list mylist
end

to-report lookup [#key]  ;; if you really want ...
  let slidername table:get mytable #key
  report (runresult slidername)
end

to test
  print runresult table:get mytable 1
  print lookup 1
  print runresult table:get mytable 3
  print lookup 3
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two sliders called `s1` and `s3` whose values should be referred by the values 1 and 3, you can build the desired list as follow:

```
 set mylist (list (list 1 s1) (list 3 s3))
```

and use your function calling

`itemz 1` or `itemz 3` to get the desired slider value